# An integral identity for unimodal distributions

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

For two unimodal densities $f_0$ and $f_1$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$, I figured out that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{f_0(x)f_1(x)}\left[\ln(f_1(x))-\ln(f_0(x))\right]\mathrm{d}x=0.$$
Why should this be true?

Thanks.

**Add**: A got this result for mean shifted Guassian and Laplace distributions for the same variance. It doesnt hold when variance is different. I think for mean shifted $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f_1(x)}{f_0(x)}\mathbb{d}x=0$ and the result should be related to this I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found out, the equality is not true in general. The equality holds, however, for mean shifted densities of a distribution that is symmetric about $0$. This has nothing to do with unimodality. More specifically, suppose $f(x)>0$ is the density of a distribution such that $f(x)=f(-x)$. Suppose also that $f_0(x)=f(x-u)$ and $f_1(x)=f(x-v)$ for some constant shifts $u$ and $v$. Let $w=\frac{u-v}2$ and $y=x-\frac{u+v}2$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{f_0(x)f_1(x)}\left[\ln(f_1(x))-\ln(f_0(x))\right]dx\\
=&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{f(y-w)f(y+w)}\left[\ln(f(y-w))-\ln(f(y+w))\right]dy.\\
\end{align*}
$$
Since the integrand is an odd function in $y$, the integral is zero.

Comment: yes thats correct. thanks.